# RStudio is not opening, just shows the RStudio logo

Tags: rstudio

I recently uninstalled the versions of R and RStudio that I had and  downloaded the latest versions of R(4.2.2) and RStudio. This is on Windows 10.

The first time I try to open RStudio after downloading the newest version, was the first time I had this problem but I closed and try to opened again and it work just fine, but now it isn't working, I also try to open the most recent work I had, that show when I click with the right click of the mouse in the rstudio logo on the taskbar and it try to open rstudio but it was a black screen and nothing else happen. What can I do?

Comment: File an issue? https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Answer (score 0):

I encountered and solved the same problem after installing the latest versions of R Studio and R(4.2.2 as I write this)

The logo was displayed as when loading without the interface ever appearing.

It appears I had 2 versions of R: the latest and and older (3.5.1).
I solved the problem by uninstalling the latest R version in my case.
I didn't need to uninstall/reinstall R Studio however.

When starting R studio just displayed a box telling me that it needs R to work, then I manually chose the R 64-bit version (3.5.1) that I possess on my computer in the menu proposed in the box.

I don't know if the issue was due to two R versions installed at the same time (the latest and an older), or specifically caused by the latest, either way uninstalling the latest R version I had solved my issue.

So you should check if you have two R versions installed, or installing an older version of R as 3.5.1. The problem seemed however unrelated to R Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem today. Only logo of "R" appears while opening R studio. After checking I got to know, I have installed two "R" versions i.e. 4.2.1 and 4.2.2. After uninstalling the old version of R (4.2.1), The R studio worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this "only logo" problem. I solved it by unchecking the auto-detect for R version in R Studio global options

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it in a very strange way.

1. From the start-up, I searched for the R version on my computer and opened the R console application (without R studio).
2. After that, I launched R studio and it opened successfully (Don't close the R console you opened in step 1 while launching R studio)
3. Next, I changed the global option to select the specific version of R (4.3.0) in R studio.

It is now opening correctly.